# Controller actions permisson specs

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm just starting with rails and testing, and not sure what's good way to dry code like this.

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe EventsController, type: :controller do
  let(:admin) { create(:user_admin) }
  let(:mod) { create(:user_moderator) }
  let(:user) { create(:user) }

  let(:link) { create(:link) }
  let(:event) { create(:event) }

  describe 'GET #new' do
    it 'allows admin user to perform action' do
      sign_in admin

      get :new, link: link.id

      expect(flash[:alert]).to_not match(/^You are not authorized to perform this action./)
    end

    it 'allows mod user to perform action' do
      sign_in mod

      get :new, link: link.id

      expect(flash[:alert]).to_not match(/^You are not authorized to perform this action./)
    end

    it 'does not allow regular user to perform action' do
      sign_in user

      get :new, link: link.id

      expect(flash[:alert]).to match(/^You are not authorized to perform this action./)
    end

    it 'does not allow guest to perform action' do
      get :new, link: link.id

      expect(flash[:alert]).to match(/^You are not authorized to perform this action./)
    end
  end

  describe 'POST #create' do
    it 'allows admin user to perform action' do
      sign_in admin

      post :create, event: attributes_for_event(event, link)

      expect(flash[:alert]).to_not match(/^You are not authorized to perform this action./)
    end

    it 'allows mod user to perform action' do
      sign_in mod

      post :create, event: attributes_for_event(event, link)

      expect(flash[:alert]).to_not match(/^You are not authorized to perform this action./)
    end

    it 'does not allow regular user to perform action' do
      sign_in user

      post :create, event: attributes_for_event(event, link)

      expect(flash[:alert]).to match(/^You are not authorized to perform this action./)
    end

    it 'does not allow guest to perform action' do
      post :create, event: attributes_for_event(event, link)

      expect(flash[:alert]).to match(/^You are not authorized to perform this action./)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please state only the code's purpose in the title.

Answer (score 1):

You could DRY the specs in the following way:

1. perform the authentication of the user in a `before` block
2. when testing a controller the `subject` could be the request itself
3. use `context` blocks for better structure
4. use functions for making the assertions when it comes to `flash` messages

So, keeping these in mind, you could write your specs like this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe EventsController, type: :controller do
  let(:link) { create(:link) }
  let(:event) { create(:event) }
  let(:admin) { create(:user_admin) }
  let(:moderator) { create(:user_moderator) }
  let(:user) { create(:user) }

  AUTHORIZATION_ERROR = /^You are not authorized to perform this action/

  describe 'GET #new' do
    subject { get :new, link: link.id  }

    before(:each) do
      sign_in(authorized_resource) if authorized_resource.present?
    end

    context 'for user with admin role' do
      let(:authorized_resource) { admin }
      it 'does not display an alert' do
        subject
        expect(flash[:alert]).to_not match(AUTHORIZATION_ERROR)
      end
    end

    context 'for user with moderator role' do
      let(:authorized_resource) { moderator }
      it 'does not display an alert' do
        subject
        expect(flash[:alert]).to_not match(AUTHORIZATION_ERROR)
      end
    end

    context 'for user with no role' do
      let(:authorized_resource) { user }
      it 'displays an alert' do
        subject
        expect(flash[:alert]).to match(AUTHORIZATION_ERROR)
      end
    end

    context 'for guest user' do
      it 'displays an alert' do
        subject
        expect(flash[:alert]).to match(AUTHORIZATION_ERROR)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It might make sense to check for response codes as well (e.g. `401 Unauthorized`, `403 Forbidden`, etc) since a flash message on its own does say much about what's going on with the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this spec needs DRY-ing. You've reduced things down to realistic usage scenarios, which is exactly what you want to do. The steps in each spec are not 100% the same, so there really isn't any code repetition.

While it may feel like you've got repeated code, your tests are explicit and easy to follow. I wouldn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I would just factor out the flash error into a constant. Also, I believe the trailing period in your regex should be escaped, as you don't want to match any character.

```
require 'rails_helper'

FLASH_ERROR = /^You are not authorized to perform this action\./

describe EventsController, type: :controller do
  let(:admin) { create(:user_admin) }
  let(:mod) { create(:user_moderator) }
  let(:user) { create(:user) }

  let(:link) { create(:link) }
  let(:event) { create(:event) }

  describe 'GET #new' do
    it 'allows admin user to perform action' do
      sign_in admin

      get :new, link: link.id

      expect(flash[:alert]).to_not match FLASH_ERROR
    end

    it 'allows mod user to perform action' do
      sign_in mod

      get :new, link: link.id

      expect(flash[:alert]).to_not match FLASH_ERROR
    end

    it 'does not allow regular user to perform action' do
      sign_in user

      get :new, link: link.id

      expect(flash[:alert]).to match FLASH_ERROR
    end

    it 'does not allow guest to perform action' do
      get :new, link: link.id

      expect(flash[:alert]).to match FLASH_ERROR
    end
  end

  describe 'POST #create' do
    it 'allows admin user to perform action' do
      sign_in admin

      post :create, event: attributes_for_event(event, link)

      expect(flash[:alert]).to_not match FLASH_ERROR
    end

    it 'allows mod user to perform action' do
      sign_in mod

      post :create, event: attributes_for_event(event, link)

      expect(flash[:alert]).to_not match FLASH_ERROR
    end

    it 'does not allow regular user to perform action' do
      sign_in user

      post :create, event: attributes_for_event(event, link)

      expect(flash[:alert]).to match FLASH_ERROR
    end

    it 'does not allow guest to perform action' do
      post :create, event: attributes_for_event(event, link)

      expect(flash[:alert]).to match FLASH_ERROR
    end
  end
end
```